# Pig script to tranpose on basis of certain criteria

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file containing data in following format:

```
abc 123 456  
cde 45 32  
efg 322 654  
abc 445 856  
cde 65 21  
efg 147 384  
abc 815 078  
efg 843 286
```

and so on. 
How can transpose it into following format using `pig`:

```
abc 123 456 cde 45 32 efg 322 654  
abc 445 856 cde 65 21 efg 147 348  
abc 815 078           efg 843 286
```

Also, in case cde is missing after abc, it should insert blank spaces instead, since it is a fixed width file.

I tried grouping but it ain't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it by writing custom loader. The easiest attempt is to extend PigStorage and override `getNext()` method making it call record reader three times, instead of 1 and produce unioned Tuple.